# Removing Stop Words from List of Strings

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, stop-words

I have a list of strings and I want to remove some stop words from this list:

```
for (int i = 0; i < simple_title.getItemCount(); i++) {
    // split the phrase into the words
    String str = simple_title.getItem(i);
    String[] title_parts = str.split(" ");
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(title_parts));
    for (int k = 0; k < list.size(); k++) {
        for (int l = 0; l < StopWords.stopwordslist.length; l++) {
            // stopwordslist is a Static Variable in class StopWords
            list.remove(StopWords.stopwordslist[l]);
        }
    }

    title_parts = list.toArray(new String[0]);
    for (String title_part : title_parts) {
        // and here I want to print the string
        System.out.println(title_part);
    }
    Arrays.fill(title_parts, null);
}
```

The problem is that after the removal of stop words I am getting the only first index of the title_part, e.g. if I have a list of strings such as:

```
 list of strings
 i am a list
 is remove stop there list...
```

after the removal of stop words I am only getting:

```
 list
 list
 remove
```

But what I should get is:

```
  list strings
  list
  remove stop list
```

I have been working on this but now I'm confused can somebody tell me please what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Please format your code before posting! Its maximum 3 keystrokes, and makes your code a more readable

Answer (score 1):

You are removing items from your `List` at an index defined by the iteration of your `StopWords` array!

So the removal is arbitrary to say the least, and would ultimately depend on the size of your stop words.

Here's a self-contained example of what you might want to do instead:

```
// defining the list of words (i.e. from your split)
List<String> listOfWords = new ArrayList<String>();
// adding some examples here (still comes from split in your case)
listOfWords.addAll(Arrays.asList("list", "of", "strings", "i", "am", "a", "list", "is", "remove", "stop", "there", "list"));
// defining an array of stop words (you probably want that as a constant somewhere else)
final String[] stopWords = {"of", "i", "am", "a", "is"};
// printing un-processed list
System.out.printf("Dirty: %s%n", listOfWords);
// invoking removeAll to remove all stop words
listOfWords.removeAll(Arrays.asList(stopWords));
// printing "clean" list
System.out.printf("Clean: %s%n", listOfWords);
```

**Output**

```
Dirty: [list, of, strings, i, am, a, list, is, remove, stop, there, list]
Clean: [list, strings, list, remove, stop, there, list]
```

Comment: but it was working fine with another list! then what should be the solution

Comment: no you are not getting my point please review my question an update has been made

Comment: @JavaNerd I think you are not getting mine. `list.remove(StopWords.stopwordslist[l]);` will remove from your `List` at an index defined by the iteration of your stop words, which again, arbitrarily removes elements from your `List`. Using `removeAll` is safer and way more elegant than your nested iterations.